# Array en poo PHP

Tags: php, array, poo

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio de poo en PHP.
Tengo que terminar bien las clases para que al ejecutarlo me aparezca:

Soy Pepe, soy de Madrid y mis colores favoritos son:

- Azul
- Blanco
- Rojo
- Verde

Tengo dudas respecto al array, ya que no se como hacer que muestre los colores como anteriormente escribí en forma de lista y ordenados alfabéticamente.

```
    -<!--Completa la codificación de la clase persona:-->
<?php
class persona {
protected $lugar; // lugar del usuario
protected $nombre; // nombre del usuario
protected $colores=array(); // array con los colores favoritos del usuario

public function __construct($unNombre,$unlugar,$unoscolores) {
    $this->nombre=$unNombre; 
    $this->lugar=$unlugar; 
    $this->colores[]=$unoscolores; 

}
public function mostrar() {
    echo 'Me llamo  '. $this->nombre;
    echo ', soy  ' . $this->lugar;
    echo ' y mis colores favoritos son: ';
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($unoscolores);


}
}

*/
$yo = new persona('Pepe','Madrid','Azul, Blanco,Verde,Rojo');
echo $yo->mostrar();
?>
```

Comment: Colores es una cadena, no un arreglo.

Comment: ¿Y como hago para convertirlo a arreglo? Debo de hacerlo para que colores sea un array

Comment: Encierra los colores entre corchetes, cada uno entre comillas (simples o dobles) y separados por comas: `$yo = new persona('Pepe', 'Madrid', ['Azul', 'Blanco', 'Verde', 'Rojo]');`

Answer (score 1):

Debes hacer referencia a la propiedad por el nombre que tiene a través de la asginación con la pseudovariable `$this->`.

En este punto a quien debes invocar es: **`$this->colores`**

Y tu código debería quedar así:

```
print_r($this->colores);
```

Con una salida así:

```
Me llamo  Pepe, soy  Madrid y mis colores favoritos son: Array
(
    [0] => Azul, Blanco,Verde,Rojo
)
```

Modifica dentro de tu método `mostrar()` el como muestras los datos del vector, deberás iterar sobre la variable que los contiene y agregarle una salida concatenada con etiquetas `ul` y `li`

```
public function mostrar() 
    {
        echo 'Me llamo  '. $this->nombre;
        echo ', soy  de: ' . $this->lugar;
        echo ' y mis colores favoritos son: ';
        echo "<ul>";
            foreach($this->colores as $color)
            {
                echo "<li>".$color."</li>";
            }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, ¿Y como podría hacer para que el array me lo mostrara uno debajo del otro en forma de lista y ordenados alfabéticamente? Se me olvidó especificar en mi pregunta eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pensé que había escrito bien la pregunta pero se me pasó eso, Es la primera vez que formulo una pregunta. Gracias por la ayuda, estoy aprendiendo y me viene muy bien.

Comment: @BetaM `', soy de ' . $this->lugar`, solo ese pequeño detalle.

Comment: @BetaM, es que en la salida dice 'soy Madrid' en lugar de 'soy **de** Madrid'

Comment: La clase podría tener un método propio para ordenar los colores, en el caso de que interese mantener por algún motivo el orden original en que fueron recibidos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, solo me queda ordenarlos alfabéticamente. He estado buscando información en manuales y demás pero no logro que nada funcione.